# Does this sound correct: "Client's service is at risk of termination"?

Tags: email

Let's say I own a business and I provide some services. I have a client which has failed to make a payment, so his service might be terminated soon. I'm receiving an email about this situation as the owner.

Can the email subject be like: **Client's service is at risk of termination**? Does this message sound correct to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely, I see nothing wrong with that!

Having said that, if you are sending this email directly to the client, perhaps it would be better to say:

> *Your* service is at risk of termination

Otherwise, it sounds passive to refer to them in the third-person when you are addressing them directly.

Hope that helps you, let me know if you need clarification or I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Off course I will write "Your service..." in the end-user's email. But here I'm asking about the email for administrator (owner). Administrator is notified that some of his clients is not paying and is at risk of termination.

Comment: Please check at the Help Center to become more familiar with the type of questions considered suitable for ELU. General writing advice (including 'Does this sound correct?' and 'Can you improve on this?' requests), where specific issues are not pinpointed, are off-topic and should not be answered.